# HTML transform issue with IE11

Tags: css, html, transform, html-table

I have a HTML Bootstrap table. I have a transform (translateX).
It works fine in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE.

Attached is the link to [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L46FX/1840/.)
Transform is

```
.relative-center-to-parent {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

When I click on the Open button in the header, it hides and shows the Submit and Cancel buttons. This works fine. the checkbox in the table body aligns itself when the table width changes. This works fine in Firefox and Chrome.

But in IE, the checkbox stays in its original position. When I click on the checkbox, then the transform is applied. To check the checkbox I have to click on it again.

So, why does IE behave differently.

Thanks,
N

Answer (score 0):

Simple IE is only good for downloading another browser ie Morzilla and Chrome. Get over it and stop designing for IE.